# metric-server : TLS handshake error from 20.99.219.64:57467: EOF

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployed metric server using :

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/download/v0.3.6/components.yaml
```

Metric server pod is running but in logs I am getting error :

```
I0601 20:00:01.321004       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 20.99.219.64:34903: EOF
I0601 20:00:01.321160       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 20.99.219.64:22575: EOF
I0601 20:00:01.332318       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 20.99.219.64:14603: EOF
I0601 20:00:01.333174       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 20.99.219.64:22517: EOF
I0601 20:00:01.351649       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 20.99.219.64:3598: EOF
```

IP : 20.99.219.64
This is not present in Cluster. I have checked using :
**kubectl get all --all-namespaces -o wide | grep "20.99.219.64"**
Nothing is coming as O/P.

I have using Calico and initialize the cluster with --pod-network-cidr=20.96.0.0/12

Also kubectl top nodes is not working, Getting error :

```
node@kubemaster:~/Desktop/dashboard$ kubectl top nodes
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get nodes.metrics.k8s.io)
```

Answer (score 0):

During deployment of metrics-server remember to add following line in args section:

```
  - args:
    - --kubelet-insecure-tls
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
```

Also add the following line at the spec:spec level outside of the previous containers level:

```
  hostNetwork: true
  restartPolicy: Always
```

Remember to apply changes.

Metrics-server attempts to authorize itself using token authentication. Please ensure that you're running your kubelets with webhook token authentication turned on.

Speaking about TLS directly. TLS message is big packet and MTU in calico is wrong so change it according [calico-project-mtu](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.4/usage/configuration/mtu).

Execute command:

`$ kubectl edit configmap calico-config -n kube-system`  and change the MTU value from 1500 to 1430.

Take a look: [metrics-server-mtu](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/145).

Answer (score 0):

I also met the this problem that I can't make metrics-server to work in my k8s cluster (kubectl version is 1.25.4). I follow the instructions above and solve the issue!

I downloaded the components.yaml file and only add the - --kubelet-insecure-tls in the args of deployment. Then I got the metrics-server work!

Comment: Hi! When you say you followed the instructions above, can you specify which instructions in your answer?